# Adding image in interactive grid in oracle apex 5.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

In apex 5.1, we can easily add image in to column in '**interactive report**' but I am facing problem in adding image in to column in  '**interactive grid**' What could be the possible solution?

Comment: Post the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You want to disable escape character of that particular column and select type 'display only'. Then its working. you can see an image in the interactive grid.